# Do Pokemon move locations without the use of lure or incense?

Tags: pokemon-go

Will Pokemon, upon spawning, always remain in the same location until caught without the use of incense or luring modules or is it possible for them to move location?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pokemon will remain at a certain location. They won't slowly move to another location, however they will disappear after certain time has passed and new ones can spawn. Because of this it could seem like they are moving but this is not the case.

Comment: They can move, but not by itself. There is a scene that a pokemon getting flying away by a hurricane, in the trailer.